# Set animation effect on button click for the same element

Tags: javascript, css

I have div something like this. H1 tag shows the data dynamically based upon the button click.

```
    <div id="quoteId" >
          <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
        </div>
<button>Show Next</button>
```

with using css3 animation effect as

```
#quoteId {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes example {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

It is working at the first time. but the problem is how to achieve this same css effect for each time when we click on button. Please let me know in case of any clarity. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse animation like this:

```js
let but = document.getElementById("button");
let div = document.getElementById("quoteId");
but.addEventListener('click', function(){
    div.classList.add("quote");
    setTimeout(() => div.classList.remove("quote"), 1000);
});
```

```css
.quote {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes example {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div id="quoteId">
    <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
</div>
<button id="button">Show Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A)With jQuery :**

```
$("#quoteId").toggleClass('anime reve');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $("#quoteId").toggleClass('anime reve');
  })
})
```

```css
.anime {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

.reve {
  animation-name: reve;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}
  50%  {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes reve {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}
  50%  {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quoteId" class="reve" >
  <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
</div>
<button>Show Next</button>
```

**B)With Pure Css :**

> Note:The :active selector is applied only while the button is pressed.

You must change html code a bit after it use `active` selector.

```
button:active + #quoteId {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
```

```css
@keyframes example {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}
  50%  {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}


button:active + #quoteId {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Show Next</button>
  <div id="quoteId">
    <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `:active` selector is applied only while the button is pressed. When you release the button, the animation will stop.

Comment: i know, so there is not better way with pure css. use of jQuery method.